# ImportError: cannot import name Poll

Tags: python, django, python-import

I have followed all the steps in this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) but I received this error. How can it be fixed?

```
dyn-72-33-214-65:mysite mona$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep  2 2013, 05:24:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from polls.models import Poll, Choice
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Poll
```

Directory structure is as follows:

```
>>> quit()
dyn-72-33-214-65:mysite mona$ pwd
/Users/mona/data_mining/mysite
dyn-72-33-214-65:mysite mona$ ls
db.sqlite3  manage.py   mysite      polls
dyn-72-33-214-65:mysite mona$ cd polls/
dyn-72-33-214-65:polls mona$ ls
__init__.py admin.py    models.pyc  views.py
__init__.pyc    models.py   tests.py
dyn-72-33-214-65:polls mona$ cd ../mysite/
dyn-72-33-214-65:mysite mona$ ls
__init__.py settings.py urls.py
__init__.pyc    settings.pyc    wsgi.py
```

Answer: Missed to add these lines in models.py
from django.db import models

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: It would be great if you could post more of your code. Import errors do not always appear cause the class/method ("poll" in this case) is missing from module. It can also appear cause there are other (import) problems in the file you are importing from.

Comment: You're going to have to show your directory structure, and where you care calling the python shell with respect to the `polls` folder.  Also, the content of the `models.py` file will help.

Comment: That error generally would indicate that `polls.models` does not include anything by the name of `Poll`. Doublecheck that you're importing from the location you're expecting. For example, `import polls.models; print poll.models` in the interactive shell.

Comment: Good.  What's inside `models.py`?

Comment: There you go as i suspected:P There was error in the file you were importing from.

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to be taking the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) there might be the case that you changed the version tutorial at some point. Keep in mind that each version of the tutorial can dither slightly.

For example in the tutorial for v1.7 it's:

```
from polls.models import Question, Choice
```

For v1.6 it's

```
from polls.models import Poll, Choice
```

If you switched the version in the middle of the tutorial, then you should check your models.py file and see what names your classes have. Import those class names. So for example if you have

```
from django.db import models

class MyQuestion(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class MyChoice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then you should import accordingly:

```
>>> from polls.models import MyQuestion, MyChoice
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted a similar answer in another thread. In my case, when I got the issue, I used

from projectname.polls.models import Poll, Choice

It worked in my case. I think I messed up creating the directories (cannot confirm this though, since it looks ok during my quick review)

Answer (score 0):

I am use
`from models import Poll, Choice`

Not 
`from polls.models import Poll, Choice`

work for me